# How to use a javascript Randomizer script to link into an iframe so that i can open from a list of links in the script

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, random

How can I change the source of an iframe from a list of random urls in a javascript randomiser. I would much like to use either js or html or css

The source code below is of my current website which links you to a random website from a list and I would like to keep the link it links to in a page that is of the same format as the box with a back button etc.

**My website:** http://www.boredombutton.co.uk

**Below is part of my code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url=[
'http://www.fallingfalling.com',
'http://www.omfgdogs.com',
];
window.onload=function()
{document.getElementById('trig').onclick=function(){
location.href=url[Math.floor(Math.random()*url.length)];}}
</script>
```

And what i would like to do is iframe the url that has been chosen in the same iframe just interchangeable.

**The whole source code of my website is this:**

```
<html>
<head>

<title>BoredomButton</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url=[
'http://www.fallingfalling.com',
'http://www.omfgdogs.com',
'http://www.republiquedesmangues.fr',
'http://www.staggeringbeauty.com',
'http://ducksarethebest.com',
'http://eelslap.com',
'http://heeeeeeeey.com',
'http://breakglasstosoundalarm.com'


];
window.onload=function()
{document.getElementById('trig').onclick=function(){
location.href=url[Math.floor(Math.random()*url.length)];}}
</script>

<body align="center"  bgcolor="#egegeg" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0"      marginheight="0">




<table align="center" id="Table_01" width="968" height="650" border="0" cellpadding="0"    cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/BoredomButton_01.png" width="968" height="363"       alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/BoredomButton_02.png" width="347" height="287" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="trig"><img src="images/BoredomButton_03.png" width="274" height="99" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/BoredomButton_04.png" width="347" height="287" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/BoredomButton_05.png" width="274" height="188" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help in advance this would really help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to load the URL in an iframe, *and* show the chosen URL somewhere on the website.

Change your function to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url=[
    'http://www.fallingfalling.com',
    'http://www.omfgdogs.com',
];
window.onload=function() {
    var theURL = url[Math.floor(Math.random()*url.length)];
    document.getElementById('trig').onclick=function() {
        location.href=theURL;
    }}
    document.getElementById('chosenURL').innerHTML = '<a href="'+theURL+'">'+theURL+'</a>';
</script>
```

Then add this HTML to your page, there where you want the text:

```
<div id="chosenURL"></div>
```

Comment: Well basically my website acts as a button that links you to many different randomised websites all in a list and what i would like is to instead of leaving the page to have the link in an iframe maybe underneath the button